# Android - Code After Looper

Tags: android, multithreading, looper

I have a child thread running to do a task infinitely. I want to (1) constantly send data back to the UI thread, and (2) occasionally send data (corresponding to buttons) to the child thread to pause/continue the infinite task. My problem is that the child thread gets stuck in the looper, meaning the task does not execute.

**My questions is this:** How do I get the child thread to receive messages from the UI thread without blocking the infinite task?

This is what I have so far:
For task (1), I have a handler in my UI thread, which works, and an infinite loop in the child thread that sends back a message, which works by itself.

In UI thread:

```
mMainHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b;
        b = msg.getData();
        if (msg.what==1)
            Log.i("main", "from child (running) - " + b.getBoolean("running"));
        else if (msg.what == 2)
            Log.i("main", "from child (count) - " + b.getInt("count"));
    }
};
```

In child thread (currently using a dummy task until I get the framework worked out):

```
while (true) {
    if (running) {
        try {
            curCount += up;
            if (curCount == maxCount)
                up = -1;
            else if (curCount == minCount)
                up = 1;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("", "local Thread error", e);
        }

        Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
        b.putInt("count", curCount);
        Message toMain = mMainHandler.obtainMessage();
        toMain.what = 2;
        toMain.setData(b);
        mMainHandler.sendMessage(toMain);
    }
}
```

For task (2), I have a method in my UI thread corresponding to a button press that sends a message to the child thread, which works, and a handler in the child thread, which works by itself.

In UI thread:

```
private void sendRunning(boolean running) {
    if (mChildHandler != null) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
        b.putBoolean("running", running);

        Message msg = mChildHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = 1;
        msg.setData(b);
        mChildHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

In child thread:

```
Looper.prepare();
mChildHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b;
        if (msg.what==1){
            b = msg.getData();
            running = b.getBoolean("running");
            Log.i(INNER_TAG, "from main (running) - " + b.getBoolean("running"));
            Log.i(INNER_TAG, "running - " + running);
            try {
                Message toMain = mMainHandler.obtainMessage();
                toMain.what = 1;
                toMain.setData(b);
                mMainHandler.sendMessage(toMain);
            } finally {}
        }
    }
};
Looper.loop();
```

Each one of those scenarios works fine alone, but trying to do both at the same time is the problem. If I put the infinite task after the Looper.loop(), it is never reached. If I put it before the Looper.prepare(), it is run once. If I put it withing the looper, it is still only run once.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is my full code (minus package/imports) for reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Thread thread;
private Handler mMainHandler, mChildHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMainHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle b;
            b = msg.getData();
            if (msg.what==1)
                Log.i("main", "from child (running) - " + b.getBoolean("running"));
            else if (msg.what == 2)
                Log.i("main", "from child (count) - " + b.getInt("count"));
        }
    };

    thread = new ChildThread();
    thread.start();

    // Get a reference to the button
    Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    Button buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    // Set the click listener to run my code
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Starting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendRunning(true);
        }
    });
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Stopping...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendRunning(false);
        }
    });
}

private void sendRunning(boolean running) {
    if (mChildHandler != null) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
        b.putBoolean("running", running);

        Message msg = mChildHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = 1;
        msg.setData(b);
        mChildHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    Log.i("tag", "stop looping the child thread's message queue");
    mChildHandler.getLooper().quit();

    super.onDestroy();

}

class ChildThread extends Thread {

    private static final String INNER_TAG = "ChildThread";
    private boolean running = true;     
    final int maxCount = 10;
    final int minCount = 0;
    public int curCount = minCount;
    private int up = 1;

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            if (running) {
                try {
                    curCount += up;
                    if (curCount == maxCount)
                        up = -1;
                    else if (curCount == minCount)
                        up = 1;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e("", "local Thread error", e);
                }

                Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
                b.putInt("count", curCount);
                Message toMain = mMainHandler.obtainMessage();
                toMain.what = 2;
                toMain.setData(b);
                mMainHandler.sendMessage(toMain);
            }

            this.setName("child");
            Looper.prepare();
            mChildHandler = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    Bundle b;
                    if (msg.what==1){
                        b = msg.getData();
                        running = b.getBoolean("running");
                        Log.i(INNER_TAG, "from main (running) - " + b.getBoolean("running"));
                        Log.i(INNER_TAG, "running - " + running);
                        try {
                            Message toMain = mMainHandler.obtainMessage();
                            toMain.what = 1;
                            toMain.setData(b);
                            mMainHandler.sendMessage(toMain);
                        } finally {}
                    }
                }
            };

            Log.i(INNER_TAG, "Child handler is bound to - " +
                    mChildHandler.getLooper().getThread().getName());
            Looper.loop();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: side note: I spent a while researching and trying to figure out how to use threads, and [this](http://codinghard.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/android-thread-messaging/) page laid it out really well. [This](http://www.biemmeitalia.net/blog/bundle-android/) page showed me how to use bundles to exchange data between threads.

Comment: if at all possible avoid running a thread indefinitely...

Answer (score 0):

Just Use Intent service rather then this thread so you can manage all UI of your update and what ever you want to do with UI in intent service one broadcast receiver is using and its very easy to handle threads and infect your your UI is nit hand or lock while your background process run .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a variable time for the thread to avoid the situation. Thanks for the advice.